# Equivalent to WebBrowser.Navigated Event in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

What is the equivalent to [WebBrowser.Navigated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) in native delphi (XE3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will be [OnNavigateComplete2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnNavigateComplete2) :

> Write an OnNavigateComplete2 event handler to take specific action
>   when the Web browser successfully navigates to a new resource. The
>   event can occur before the document is fully downloaded, but when it
>   occurs at least part of the document must be received and a viewer for
>   the document created.

[WebBrowser.Navigated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) :

> Handle the Navigated event to receive notification when the WebBrowser
>   control has navigated to a new document. When the Navigated event
>   occurs, the new document has begun loading, which means you can access
>   the loaded content through the Document, DocumentText, and
>   DocumentStream properties. Handle the DocumentCompleted event to
>   receive notification when the WebBrowser control finishes loading the
>   new document.

Answer (score 2):

The [`TWebBrowser.OnNavigateComplete2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnNavigateComplete2) event.